# creating a new csv file with open() in specific directory

Tags: python, save

My script creates a new csv file based on the date. It default saves the file the the local directory. Any idea how i can save it to a specific folder? Thx

```
    with open('record ' + str(current) + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add to the `open` functions path argument like so:

```
with open(folder_path + '/' + 'record ' + str(current) + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
```

Assuming that `folder_path` holds a path to the specified folder like `'/home/users/you/somefolder'`

But I would suggest looking into using [`PathLib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for path creation & manipulation

Answer (score 0):

the file parameter in the open function is the path to such file. By indicating only the filename it's assumed as a file on the actual directory, so for writing it anywhere on your drive (as long as you have permissions) you should use full path

```
with open('/tmp/record ' + str(current) + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
```